# Extjs 6.5 build and class files

Tags: extjs, build, manifest

I am facing an issue where my classes could not be loaded properly by bootstrap.js file.

I am using the classic toolkit, and I can build in development mode successfully. However when I load the application, it is trying to get files with the wrong path.

For example, it will attempt to load `app/MyAppNs/view/sample/SampleView.js` instead of `app/classic/src/view/sample/SampleView.js`. I checked the content of the manifest file, and I could not find the view in the paths section yet the files physically exist under the app folders (classic/src/).

This happens to several classes and not just views (like controllers, stores, helpers classes etc).

Does anyone know and can explain how the manifest file is generated?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, we finally managed to find the root cause for this; I have [a post on sencha forum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?469672-Unable-to-load-the-view-files&p=1317474#post1317474) where I put the resolution.

Cheers